# Finding popular keywords in huge list

Tags: algorithm, popularity

I have a huge list with about 100 000 lines like this:

- ipadnews
- abcipad
- cddeeffipad
- hellworld
- iworldthis
  .. and so on

And would like to find popular substrings, in this case "ipad" would be the most popular and "world" would be on second place. Minimum length should be three or four chars.

I can't predict the substrings so using a dictionary is a no no.

Comment: a substring isn't a "keyword" per se.

Comment: what are keywords then? any substring of the words found in your list? it sure sounds like that... and it's a hell of a complexity

Comment: How is the algorithm supposed to know that "world" is an acceptable keyword, but now "worl" or "orld"?

Comment: @Wooble, @Playcat: Good point! Should be substring and not keyword. Thanks

Comment: @Axn: You don't know until you do the matching of popular substrings

Answer (score 4):

This is a relatively complicated problem ... but it's tractable using prefix/suffix trees. It's essentially a variation of the [longest common subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) and [longest common substring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) problems. - which is where I would start.

There's actually quite [a bit of research](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960229.html) on problems on this form - you should be able to use the terms above to narrow your search.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this using a [generalized suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_suffix_tree) which can be built in `O(n)` time. This is effectively a play on the [LCS problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem).

Answer (score 0):

I would go about this problem using the following flow of logic:

1. Extract the set of suffixes for each word. So from 'ipadnews' we get: 'ipadnews', 'padnews', 'adnews', and so on. This way, 'news' will be one of the suffixes, but not 'ipad'.
2. To make up for the missing substrings in the above step, extract the prefixes as well. We get 'ipadnew', 'ipadne', and so on, including 'ipad'.
3. For each of the substrings above, hash them towards a count, e.g. $hash{$substr}++.

At the end we will have a long hashtable with frequency of words as values. Instead of an expensive sorting, suppose you only want 10 most popular words. Keep a set from the beginning whose criteria is that any word in it must have a score more than the current min score. You can keep track of the word with min score and when you add the 11th item with score more than the min score, bump out the word with the min score and update the min score pointer.

The max number of keys in the hashtable will be 2*k*n where k is the average length of the words and n is total number of words.

Comment: This won't find "world" in "iworldthis", which OP seems to expect.  May require extracting the set of prefixes from each element of the set of suffixes?